# Java. Добавление манифеста в pom.xml не находит main

Tags: java, xml, apache, maven, apache-modules

У меня задание сделать так что бы приложение запускалось командой:

`java –jar tracker.jar.`

Я добавил с сайта майвена менифест https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html

Но мне все равно пишет:

```
Mac-mini-Pavel:tracker pavel$ java –jar tracker.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class –jar
```

Я в этом блоке от оригинала на сайте поменял только эту строчку

```
 <mainClass>ru.pravvich.start.StartUI</mainClass>
```

Остальное оставил как было.
Подскажите возможно надо добавить еще что-то?
В целом мой манифест выглядит так:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>ru.pravvich.start.StartUI</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Используйте дефис вместо тире: `-jar` вместо `–jar`.

Comment: То же самое не помогает.

Comment: И какая ошибка теперь возникает?

Comment: такая-же что с дефисом что с минусом((

Comment: Теперь он не находит `tracker.jar`. А этот файл есть в текущей папке? Вы выполнили сборку через maven? Имейте в виду, maven помещает готовый jar в папку `target`, а не в текущую.

Comment: Все разобрался. Дело было не в бабине... Там файл назывался не tracker.jar а tracker-1.0.jar вот и все. Всем спасибо!

Comment: Было бы замечательно посмотреть что же у Вас внутри tracker.jar-файла (что там в файле-манифесте прописано). Плагин maven имеет множество настроек. Надо использовать наиболее подходящие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения задачи ("

```
У меня задание сделать так что бы приложение запускалось командой:

java –jar tracker.jar.
```

") с помощью возможностей IDE Eclipse (Version: Neon.1 (4.6.1)):

1. *Создаём простой (simple) проект Maven **ru.pravvich.start**.*

   [image: Создание проекта Maven]
2. *Заполняем pom-файл содержанием:*

[image: Добавление плагина][image: Дабавление кофигурационной информации]

```html
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>ru.pravvich</groupId>
        <artifactId>ru.pravvich.start</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Tracker</name>
        <description>Creating tracker.jar. Just do it.</description>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>tracker</finalName>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>ru.pravvich.start.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

3. *Настраиваем запуск команды Maven (mvn jar:jar) средствами Eclipse IDE*
   [image: Настройка команд Maven]
4. *Локализуем jar-файл:*

   [image: Локализация jar-файла]
5. *Запускаем jar-файл:*
   [image: Запуск jar-файла]

Answer (score 0):

Приложение НЕ собирается, а запускается командой `java -jar tracker.jar`.

Cобирается командой `mvn package` или если без maven'а `jar cf tracker.jar *.class`

Comment: Да да описался... запускается

Comment: теперь такая ошибка

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile tracker.jar

Comment: А понятно с дефисом он main не находит а с минусом вообще jar открыть не может. Ну это прогресс хотя бы про дефис теперь знаю... Спасибо Roman. Но что дальше то делать?

Comment: может какое-то из этих решений подойдет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-access-jar-file